# Use marker icon with only awesome fonts, no surrounding balloon

Tags: leaflet, font-awesome, markers

I have this code that works fine, but I need to get only the icon to show and not the "balloon" with its shadow.

I have tried with removing "`markerColor`..." but that is only changing to the default blue marker / balloon.

How to only show the icon and its size and color?

```js
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
  var con = feature.properties.concept;

  var hub;

  // icons for XX, YY and ZZ 
  if (kon === 'XX') {
    hub = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'truck', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'cadetblue'}) });
  } else if (kon === 'YY') {
    hub = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'envelope', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'blue'}) });
  } else if (kon === 'ZZ') {
    hub = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'bicycle', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue'}) });
  } else {
    hub = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'envelope-o', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'red'}) });
  }
  return hub;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, [Leaflet.awesome-markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) plugin does not offer you the option to display *only* the inner icon (from Font Awesome or whatever source) *without* the surrounding balloon.

Same for its [cloned version](https://github.com/sigma-geosistemas/Leaflet.awesome-markers) and other variations like [Leaflet.extra-markers](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) plugin.

But you can very simply use a Leaflet [`DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#divicon) instead:

> Represents a lightweight icon for markers that uses a simple `<div>` element instead of an image. Inherits from `Icon` but ignores the `iconUrl` and shadow options.

Then you simply fill that `<div>` container with your Font Awesome icon, the same way you would do it in a normal page, and what the Leaflet.awesome-markers plugin does under the hood for you:

```js
L.marker(latlng, {
  icon: L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-truck" style="color: red"></i>',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myDivIcon'
  })
});
```

Note that you also have to specify a bit of CSS to customize it as you wish:

```css
.myDivIcon {
  text-align: center; /* Horizontally center the text (icon) */
  line-height: 20px; /* Vertically center the text (icon) */
}
```

Example:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

L.marker([48.86, 2.35], {
  icon: L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-truck" style="color: red"></i>',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myDivIcon'
  })
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.myDivIcon {
  text-align: center; /* Horizontally center the text (icon) */
  line-height: 20px; /* Vertically center the text (icon) */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.awesome-markers@2.0.4/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.awesome-markers@2.0.4/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: That is the best answer. Saved me so much frustration. @QGIS-user you should accept this answer!