# Custom fonts with L.divIcon Leaflet not showing

Tags: css, fonts, leaflet

Using the icomoon internet service to create custom icon-fonts, having trouble to make them visible on Leaflet map. Somehow I can not fetch the icons, what have I missed!? I have the data on the map as I can open up the popup, the problem is there is no icons visible....

I have the fonts folder in the correct place and stylesheet is loaded
This is part of the CSS from icomoon I have in a custom-style.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:  url('myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.eot?bf4cat');
src:  url('myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.eot?bf4cat#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.ttf?bf4cat') format('truetype'),
url('myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.woff?bf4cat') format('woff'),
url('myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.svg?bf4cat#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-display: block;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
/* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
speak: never;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;

/* Better Font Rendering =========== */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-bb .path1:before {
  content: "\e900";
  color: rgb(35, 31, 32);
}
.icon-bb .path2:before {
  content: "\e901";
  margin-left: -1em;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.icon-bb .path3:before {
  content: "\e902";
  margin-left: -1em;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
} etc....
```

Then I created a function to look for customer name and give them a className

```
function getCustomer(x){
        x === 'customerBB'          ? 'icon- icon-bb' :
        x === 'customerCA'          ? 'icon- icon-ca' :
        x === 'customerCE'          ? 'icon- icon-ce' :
                                      'leaflet-div-icon'; //default blue icon if no match
```

Then a function to return className depending on the results found in feature.properties.customer_name

```
    var setDivIcon = function(feature){
      return {
        className: getCustomer(feature.properties.customer_name)
      };        
    }

   var customerIcon = L.divIcon(setDivIcon);
```

Later on I use the pointToLayer to add the GeoJSON to the map

```
    customerLayer = L.geoJson(json, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var time = feature.properties.timeMean_numb;
    var point
       
      if (time < 0.167){
        point = L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.divIcon(setDivIcon(feature)) }).addTo(time_1);
      }
       else if (time >= 0.167 && time <= 0.334){
        point = L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.divIcon(setDivIcon(feature)) }).addTo(time_2);
      }
```

Comment: Look for errors in your [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), and specifically check if the `myplace/customer/fonts/icomoon.eot` file is requested in the network section of the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Are you able to have icons show up in a normal `<span>`, outside Leaflet? Given your CSS sample, I would expect class path1/2/3 to be required. Then in the context of a Leaflet DivIcon, you _might_ need to rather apply thoses class names on a child Element of the DivIcon, rather than directly on the DivIcon itself.

Comment: As for the DivIcon content, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099987/use-marker-icon-with-only-awesome-fonts-no-surrounding-balloon/49103637?r=SearchResults#49103637

Comment: no errors in console, I do now get a leaflet default blue circle. When using the element selector in devtools I have the following: `code`<path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1239,894a10,10 0 1,0 20,0 a10,10 0 1,0 -20,0 "></path>`code` I guess I have to dig in deeper in the icomoon documents "how to"

Comment: @IvanSanchez did have a look at the network section, can not see any info about the icomoon.eot unfortunately. Perhaps I need a different approach to this...

Answer (score 0):

In your fontface rule you are missing some src:? This could explain them not being fetched

Comment: No difference, still same problem